# Root filesystem randomly remounts itself as readonly after a few hours (Fresh install 11.10)

Tags: 11.10

The root filesystem itself randomly read-only (usually about 3-4hrs after reboot) and needs to be restarted to be able to work again.  I've done a fresh install after the problem first appeared after an update but the same problem still exists.  What information about the system do you need to help?  It's a 64-bit OS and the root file system resides on an SSD.  I've run fsck checks on the file system (even after I reformatted the drive).  I've also looked at the SMART data and it looks good.  I'm usually able to find solutions to my problems with google but I wasn't able to this time.  Thanks for all the help.

Output of dmesg at the time of the error:

```
[ 3633.888132] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[ 3633.888144] ata2.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE
[ 3633.888159] ata2.00: cmd e7/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
[ 3633.888162]          res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[ 3633.888169] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 3633.888179] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 3643.908112] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
[ 3643.908124] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 3653.928109] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
[ 3653.928121] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 3664.500117] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 3688.932102] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
[ 3688.932115] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[ 3688.932122] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 3694.124121] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
[ 3694.124132] ata2: reset failed, giving up
[ 3694.124138] ata2.00: disabled
[ 3694.124146] ata2.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 3694.124164] ata2: EH complete
[ 3694.124286] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.124292] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.124301] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 11 79 5f 00 04 00 00
[ 3694.124319] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1145183
[ 3694.124329] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 80896

Tons of these errors...

[ 3694.125102] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 81023
[ 3694.125111] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 915749 (offset 0 size 524288 starting block 143275)
[ 3694.125135] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.125139] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.125147] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 11 7d 5f 00 04 00 00
[ 3694.125164] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1146207
[ 3694.125170] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 81024

Tons of these errors...


[ 3694.125939] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 81151
[ 3694.125947] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 915749 (offset 524288 size 524288 starting block 143403)
[ 3694.125964] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.125969] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.125976] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 11 81 5f 00 03 40 00
[ 3694.125991] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1147231
[ 3694.125998] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 81152

More of these same Buffer I/O errors...

[ 3694.126618] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 81255
[ 3694.126626] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 915749 (offset 1048576 size 425984 starting block 143507)
[ 3694.126641] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.126645] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.126653] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 01 14 4e 67 00 00 50 00
[ 3694.126668] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18108007
[ 3694.126674] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 2201249

More of the same types of errors...

[ 3694.126728] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 2201256
[ 3694.126738] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 915753 (offset 0 size 32768 starting block 2263508)
[ 3694.126747] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 2201257
[ 3694.126754] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 2201258
[ 3694.126762] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 915754 (offset 0 size 8192 starting block 2263510)
[ 3694.126776] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.126781] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.126788] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 01 14 4e b7 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.126804] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18108087
[ 3694.126811] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 2201259
[ 3694.126827] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 524657 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 2263511)
[ 3694.126842] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.126847] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.126854] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 0b 27 fe 00 00 50 00
[ 3694.126870] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 84617214
[ 3694.126984] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 749396

More errors...

[ 3694.126986] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 749397
[ 3694.127004] EXT4-fs warning (device sda4): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 1043424 (offset 1359872 size 40960 starting block 10577161)
[ 3694.127016] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127021] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127028] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 1f d5 9e 00 00 88 00
[ 3694.127043] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 85972382
[ 3694.127050] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 918784

More errors...

[ 3694.127147] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 918800
[ 3694.127155] EXT4-fs warning (device sda4): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 1042831 (offset 0 size 69632 starting block 10746564)
[ 3694.127169] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127174] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127181] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 1f d9 1e 00 01 08 00
[ 3694.127196] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 85973278
[ 3694.127202] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 918896

More errors...

[ 3694.127396] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 918928
[ 3694.127405] EXT4-fs warning (device sda4): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 1042831 (offset 458752 size 135168 starting block 10746692)
[ 3694.127418] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127422] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127429] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 28 91 d6 00 00 20 00
[ 3694.127444] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 86544854
[ 3694.127451] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 990343
[ 3694.127463] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 990344
[ 3694.127469] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 990345
[ 3694.127475] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 990346
[ 3694.127484] EXT4-fs warning (device sda4): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 1043425 (offset 4747264 size 16384 starting block 10818110)
[ 3694.127497] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127502] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127509] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 28 ee ce 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.127524] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 86568654
[ 3694.127531] quiet_error: 18 callbacks suppressed
[ 3694.127536] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 993318
[ 3694.127541] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3694.127554] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127558] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127566] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 2c 2d 6e 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.127581] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 86781294
[ 3694.127587] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 1019898
[ 3694.127592] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3694.127608] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127626] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sda4-8
[ 3694.127628] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127636] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 b5 49 1e 00 00 78 00
[ 3694.127651] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 95766814
[ 3694.127674] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127679] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127686] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 06 3e ef 16 00 00 40 00
[ 3694.127702] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 104787734
[ 3694.127708] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270703
[ 3694.127715] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270704
[ 3694.127733] Aborting journal on device sda4-8.
[ 3694.127729] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270705
[ 3694.127737] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270706
[ 3694.127745] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270707
[ 3694.127754] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270708
[ 3694.127760] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270709
[ 3694.127766] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3270710
[ 3694.127775] EXT4-fs warning (device sda4): ext4_end_bio:258: I/O error writing to inode 1042850 (offset 0 size 32768 starting block 13098474)
[ 3694.127791] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127795] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127802] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 06 40 43 a6 00 00 48 00
[ 3694.127818] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 104874918
[ 3694.127847] EXT4-fs error (device sda4) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5641: Journal has aborted
[ 3694.127852] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127857] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127864] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3694.127889] EXT4-fs (sda4): delayed block allocation failed for inode 265108 at logical offset 0 with max blocks 9 with error -5
[ 3694.127902] EXT4-fs (sda4): This should not happen!! Data will be lost
[ 3694.127911] 
[ 3694.127920] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.127927] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.127938] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3694.127948] EXT4-fs error (device sda4) in ext4_da_writepages:3033: IO failure
[ 3694.127960] Write(10): 2a 00 04 af ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.127984] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 78622110
[ 3694.127981] Write(10)
[ 3694.127997] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 0
[ 3694.128024] :
[ 3694.128028] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3694.128035]  2a 00 02 4c 04 2f 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.128047] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 38536239
[ 3694.128055] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 38536239
[ 3694.128074] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.128083] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.128098] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05
[ 3694.128125] Aborting journal on device sda2-8.
[ 3694.128134]  b3 ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.128157] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 95661470
[ 3694.128171] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 2129920
[ 3694.128184] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3694.128231] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.128240] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.128255] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 02 4b 99
[ 3694.128293] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.128308] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.128325] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 07 99 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.128370] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 498015
[ 3694.128385]  5f
[ 3694.128392] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 0
[ 3694.128404] lost page write due to I/O error on sda2
[ 3694.128417]  00 00 08 00
[ 3694.128439] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 38508895
[ 3694.128451] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 4751360
[ 3694.128461] lost page write due to I/O error on sda2
[ 3694.128485] JBD2: I/O error detected when updating journal superblock for sda2-8.
[ 3694.128493] JBD2: I/O error detected when updating journal superblock for sda4-8.
[ 3694.128543] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_journal_start_sb:296: 
[ 3694.128555] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.128565] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.128582] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write same(16): 93 08 00 00 00 00 05 20 19 9e 00 00 00 c8 00 00
[ 3694.128643] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 85989790
[ 3694.128658] Detected aborted journal
[ 3694.128671] EXT4-fs (sda2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 3694.128681] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.128691] EXT4-fs (sda2): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 3694.128705] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.128720] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 09 15 e7 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.128776] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 595431
[ 3694.128787] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 12177
[ 3694.128796] lost page write due to I/O error on sda2
[ 3694.128814] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.128823] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.128837] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 10 71 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.128892] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1077599
[ 3694.128902] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 72448
[ 3694.128911] lost page write due to I/O error on sda2
[ 3694.128940] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sda2-8
[ 3694.128988] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.128997] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.129012] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write same(16): 93 08 00 00 00 00 01 14 4e 67 00 00 00 50 00 00
[ 3694.129091] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18108007
[ 3694.129124] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.129133] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.129147] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3694.129156] journal commit I/O error
[ 3694.129165] Write(10): 2a 00 00 07 99 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.129204] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 498015
[ 3694.129217] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 0
[ 3694.129229] lost page write due to I/O error on sda2
[ 3694.129445] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.129456] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.129466] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 04 af ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.129486] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 78622110
[ 3694.129496] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 0
[ 3694.129502] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3694.129539] EXT4-fs (sda4): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 3694.129592] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.129597] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.129605] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 04 af ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.129622] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 78622110
[ 3694.129655] EXT4-fs error (device sda4): ext4_journal_start_sb:296: 
[ 3694.129665] EXT4-fs error (device sda4) in ext4_dirty_inode:5768: Journal has aborted
[ 3694.129679] EXT4-fs (sda4): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 3694.129688] Detected aborted journal
[ 3694.129694] EXT4-fs (sda4): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 3694.129748] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.129755] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.129764] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 04 af ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.129783] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 78622110
[ 3694.129853] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3694.129859] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3694.129867] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 04 af ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3694.129884] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 78622110
[ 3694.129933] EXT4-fs (sda4): ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start: 654 pages, ino 265108; err -30
[ 3699.128384] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128393] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128403] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 2f ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128422] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 87010718
[ 3699.128430] quiet_error: 3 callbacks suppressed
[ 3699.128437] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 1048576
[ 3699.128442] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128461] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128466] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128473] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 2f ae 1e 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128489] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 87010846
[ 3699.128495] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 1048592
[ 3699.128500] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128510] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128515] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128522] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 2f b7 5e 00 00 10 00
[ 3699.128537] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 87013214
[ 3699.128542] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 1048888
[ 3699.128547] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128553] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 1048889
[ 3699.128558] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128568] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128573] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128579] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 30 cc 9e 00 00 10 00
[ 3699.128594] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 87084190
[ 3699.128600] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 1057760
[ 3699.128604] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128610] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 1057761
[ 3699.128615] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128625] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128630] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128637] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 06 2f ad be 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128652] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 103787966
[ 3699.128657] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3145732
[ 3699.128662] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128672] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128676] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128683] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 06 3f ad c6 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128698] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 104836550
[ 3699.128703] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 3276805
[ 3699.128708] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128718] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128722] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128729] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 06 af af 6e 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128744] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 112177006
[ 3699.128749] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 4194362
[ 3699.128754] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128764] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128768] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128775] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 06 b0 b5 8e 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128790] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 112244110
[ 3699.128795] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 4202750
[ 3699.128800] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3699.128811] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128815] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128822] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 06 b0 b8 0e 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128837] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 112244750
[ 3699.128848] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128852] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128859] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 04 ef ad d6 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128874] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 82816470
[ 3699.128884] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128889] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128896] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 04 ef ae 16 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128910] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 82816534
[ 3699.128921] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3699.128925] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3699.128932] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 2b f6 ee 00 00 08 00
[ 3699.128947] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 86767342
[ 3704.688655] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3704.688665] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3704.688675] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 06 b0 b5 8e 00 00 08 00
[ 3704.688693] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 112244110
[ 3704.688729] EXT4-fs (sda4): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 3704.688761] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3704.688766] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3704.688773] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 04 af ad 9e 00 00 08 00
[ 3704.688789] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 78622110
[ 3704.688796] quiet_error: 4 callbacks suppressed
[ 3704.688802] Buffer I/O error on device sda4, logical block 0
[ 3704.688807] lost page write due to I/O error on sda4
[ 3704.688826] EXT4-fs error (device sda4): ext4_find_entry:934: inode #1043414: comm firefox: reading directory lblock 0
[ 3709.562729] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.562738] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.562748] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0e 1b df 00 00 20 00
[ 3709.562766] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68033503
[ 3709.562896] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.562906] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.562915] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0e 1b df 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.562935] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68033503
[ 3709.563271] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.563281] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.563290] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0e 1b df 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.563309] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68033503
[ 3709.563688] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.563697] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.563705] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0e 1c 5f 00 00 20 00
[ 3709.563722] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68033631
[ 3709.563780] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.563787] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.563794] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0e 1c 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.563811] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68033631
[ 3709.564363] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.564370] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.564378] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 03 8c 20 5f 00 00 20 00
[ 3709.564395] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 59514975
[ 3709.564476] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.564483] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.564491] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 03 8c 20 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.564507] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 59514975
[ 3709.564814] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.564822] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.564830] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 03 8c 20 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.564847] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 59514975
[ 3709.565627] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.565636] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.565645] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 03 8c 20 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.565664] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 59514975
[ 3709.565921] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.565928] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.565936] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 03 8c 20 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.565952] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 59514975
[ 3709.566243] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.566245] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.566248] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 03 8c 20 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.566252] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 59514975
[ 3709.566500] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3709.566507] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3709.566516] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 03 8c 20 5f 00 00 08 00
[ 3709.566533] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 59514975
```

/etc/fstab:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f83e5cde-9d70-422f-a386-b0a75813a29b /               ext4    defaults,noatime 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ff0e7521-c1bb-4278-b0e0-e215f107428e /boot           ext2    defaults,noatime 0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=f378f105-8c39-4f34-a2e1-9852c627166e /home           ext4    defaults,noatime 0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=2b42d60c-c73a-433c-a368-58dd65fac03a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this happened to me maybe a half dozen times with a Patriot SSD, before the disk just [disappeared entirely](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/hard-lesson-learned-hard-way-about-ssds.html) and I had to RMA it.

Comment: can U add the info of your /etc/fstab please?

Comment: @DustinKirkland That's what I'm afraid of, but I want to make sure everything else is working first before I try to RMA a drive that's over a year old (not sure if it's out of warranty or not)

Comment: So I called the manufacturer and it's still under warranty, so if everyone recommends RMA'ing the drive, I can.  I just wanna make sure it's not an ubuntu error first before going through the whole process.

Comment: I'd agree to it being a dying hard disk. Be sure to back up your data!

Comment: @roadmr Thanks for the help.  I've already pulled the disk, now just to install ubuntu on one of my other drives while I wait for the manufacturer.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Also, since I'm new at asking questions... how do I close this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to interpret these errors from syslog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9606/how-to-interpret-these-errors-from-syslog)

Answer (score 2):

Had this same issue with some dell blades running ubuntu.
It was a drive caching issue with the RAID mirror.
Also a firmware update needed by seagate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add  [remount to your fstab:](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/mount.8.html)

> **remount**
>      Attempt  to  remount  an  already-mounted  filesystem.   This is
>      commonly used to  change  the  mount  flags  for  a  filesystem               especially  to  make a readonly filesystem writable. It does not
>                     change device or mount point.

Comment: Remount usually makes sense only when you run the mount command, not in fstab, and it doesn't solve the underlying issue that his hard disk seems to be dying / misbehaving.