# Installing or running ubuntu from USB

Tags: installation, disk, inspiron

I made a boot USB and stuck it in before I launched my computer.

The Ubuntu screen appeared in black, with options, I chose to install on it on my hard-drive.  Everything was fine until it got to the stage when the text on the screen displayed **ata1.00: error: {UNC}**. Then it showed **ata1: EH complete**

It repeatedly showing those two messages and it goes on and on nonstop

What can I do?

The original problem was that my Dell Inspiron Mini 10 had  Windows 7 installed, crashed and on start-up started showing the message: **operating system not found.**

Thats when I decided to try Ubuntu and that's what happened.

Comment: when restarting with the Live USB, have you try the option "try" instead of "install". Try it now anyway, it may help you discovering the source of the problem. In general, always try before installing.

Comment: i agree to try ubuntu. This will run ubuntu from live usb disk. your error is related with hard disk failure. get a new hard disk.

Comment: is you can boot your computer from live usb - choose try ubuntu. than open gparted and try to test your hdd and posibily fix.

Comment: your original problem (operating system not found.) may be due to failed hdd as well

Answer (score 0):

this old Ubuntu Ask question sounds similar to your problem.

[how to interpret these errors from syslog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9606/how-to-interpret-these-errors-from-syslog)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.