# Unable to mount hard disk

Tags: installation, mount, filesystem, hard-drive

I am unable to mount hard disk and got this message:

```
Unable to mount 158 GB Filesystem
Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so
```

From the terminal, I tried `syslog - try`:

```
No command 'syslog' found, did you mean:
Command 'dsyslog' from package 'dsyslog' (universe)
Command 'syslogd' from package 'sysklogd' (universe)
Command 'syslogd' from package 'inetutils-syslogd' (universe)
Command 'syslogd' from package 'busybox-syslogd' (universe)
syslog: command not found
```

Also tried `dmesg | tail`:

```
[ 971.390588] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 12 62 30 80 00 00 40 00
[ 971.390600] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 308424832
[ 971.390605] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424840)
[ 971.390608] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424848)
[ 971.390617] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424856)
[ 971.390620] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424864)
[ 971.390623] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424872)
[ 971.390626] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424880)
[ 971.390629] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424888)
[ 971.390632] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:308424896)
```

It was fine before I tried to re-install 12.04 from the live CD (which failed due to the disk problem).

Comment: So... what was the command you were originally trying to mount with? It sounds like you tried to mount it as the wrong filesystem (e.g., NTFS instead of EXT4,) and that you also specified an invalid flag (e.g., `-tw` instead of `-rw`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to interpret these errors from syslog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9606/how-to-interpret-these-errors-from-syslog)

Answer (score 1):

Boot off the LiveCD and try:

```
sudo mount errors=remount-ro /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

If this manages to mount the drive in read only mode, you should back up any important data that you may have which should now be accessible at /mnt/home/your_user_name/

If it complains about not knowing what the filesystem type is, try

```
sudo mount -t ext2 errors=remount-ro /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

It seems the device might be failing if it's not completely dead.  You won't know for sure until you back it up and try to reformat from scratch and test it.  Anything that says "read error" is pretty bad news and I don't think it's a good candidate for recovery as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Boot machine using live CD, open terminal and unmount other partitions excluding the 158 GB partition and type:

```
sudo  fsck /dev/sdaX
```

where X is your 158 GB partition.

Comment: The read errors are a concern.  I don't think I'd try to write to this drive until an attempt at read-only backup has been done.