# Slow boot & a lot of crash/internal error reports

Tags: boot, lenovo

Any idea what might be the problem here? I have an lenovo u410 with a samsung SSD 840pro, i3 processor running ubuntu 13.10.

Very slow boot times and a lot of crash reports and internal error reports.
I've tried a fresh install but still the same.

It came with a 24GB mSATA (SDA) that seems to have failed but I'm not using it so don't know should I remove it or not as its seems to be giving IO errors.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated..

```
17:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   64.873067]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov 17 12:17:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   64.873070] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov 17 12:17:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   64.873080] ata1: hard resetting link
Nov 17 12:17:28 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   70.231360] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Nov 17 12:17:33 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   74.877827] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
Nov 17 12:17:33 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   74.877838] ata1: hard resetting link
Nov 17 12:17:38 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   80.236121] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Nov 17 12:17:43 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   84.882651] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
Nov 17 12:17:43 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   84.882661] ata1: hard resetting link
Nov 17 12:17:48 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [   90.240930] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Nov 17 12:18:01 aron-Lenovo-U410 NetworkManager[665]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
Nov 17 12:18:18 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  119.911607] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
Nov 17 12:18:18 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  119.911618] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
Nov 17 12:18:18 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  119.911621] ata1: hard resetting link
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 udisksd[1989]: Error probing device: Error sending ATA command IDENTIFY DEVICE to /dev/sda: Unexpected sense data returned:#0120000: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00    ................#0120010: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00    ................#012 (g-io-error-quark, 0)
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.933964] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.933974] ata1: reset failed, giving up
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.933978] ata1.00: disabled
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.933983] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.933998] ata1: EH complete
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934035] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934038] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934040] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934042] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934044] Read(10): 28 00 02 cb b4 d0 00 00 08 00
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934052] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 46904528
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934056] quiet_error: 162 callbacks suppressed
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934058] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 5863066
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934146] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934156] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934162] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934171] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934176] Read(10): 28 00 02 cb b4 d0 00 00 08 00
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934194] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] READ CAPACITY(16) failed
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934198] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934200] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934203] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934207] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 46904528
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934216] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 5863066
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934319] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] READ CAPACITY failed
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934327] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934331] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934336] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934378] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934384] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934388] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934393] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934397] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934419] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2048
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934424] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 256
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934494] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934499] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934502] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934508] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934511] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934526] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2048
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934531] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934535] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934539] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 256
Nov 17 12:18:23 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  124.934570] sda: detected capacity change from 24015495168 to 0
Nov 17 12:18:55 aron-Lenovo-U410 whoopsie[913]: online
Nov 17 12:18:56 aron-Lenovo-U410 whoopsie[913]: online
Nov 17 12:19:04 aron-Lenovo-U410 NetworkManager[665]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
Nov 17 12:19:04 aron-Lenovo-U410 whoopsie[913]: online
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to interpret these errors from syslog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9606/how-to-interpret-these-errors-from-syslog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Very slow boot times and a lot of crash reports and internal error reports. I've tried a fresh install but still the same.

This is normally a hardware issue. Check your cables and disk. Save all important information. Other than that... pray and prepare to buy new things.

Comment: thanks for your reply Braiam, would you reccomend runnuning: sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb or something else?

Comment: also wold you recommend removing the failed mSATA SDA? or would that even cause a problem as ive installed everything on the SSD SDB?

Comment: I wouldn't use anything that I know is failing...

Comment: Ive removed the mSATA and boot times have reduced dramatically, so happy days. When I get to my welcome screen I still get about 5 error reports though. I have this error in my log over and over: Nov 17 19:02:55 aron-Lenovo-U410 kernel: [  372.682844] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1.

Comment: @Aron that's another question.