# Can't start apache2 with error "bus error"

Tags: apache2

Does anyone know what cause my apache2 couldn't start properly in ubuntu?

I ran `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`

outputs

```
* Starting web server apache2 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: \
        line 132: 29125 Bus error (core dumped)  \
        $HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENTS} -k $ARGV Action 'start' failed. \
        The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Show the error log. Should be somewhere like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: hi, i can't see anything on apache2 log, there's empty. Have any idea?

Comment: but while i'm watching log from syslog and running apache
tail -f /var/log/syslog
displaying

Feb  5 14:53:29 webdev kernel: [4325865.992350] Read(10): 28 00 00 b2 0d 58 00 00 08 00
Feb  5 14:53:29 webdev kernel: [4325865.992367] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 11668827
Feb  5 14:53:29 webdev kernel: [4325865.993969] ata1: EH complete

Comment: Maybe try `sudo service apache2 start`? How did you install Apache? Might have something to do with the install method.

Comment: That `I/O error, dev sda` points to broken hardware.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to interpret these errors from syslog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9606/how-to-interpret-these-errors-from-syslog)

Answer (score -1):

I was getting **(core dumped)** when starting httpd because my /var/log partition was full.  Removing old/large apache logfiles allowed me to start the service without the specific error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/556338)

Comment: It answered the question precisely... What do you mean?

Comment: You answered it *precisely*? Did your full `/var` partition cause OP's Apache web server to fail to run? Or do you have a magic 8-ball that tells you *precisely* why OP's server isn't starting? (scnr)

Comment: For what it's worth there is nothing that points to a full file system being the cause of OP's issue. And it's still a leap of thought from your issue to OP's that would have been easy for you to make in your “answer”. While your “answer“ may provide a useful hint to the cause of the problem it's also useless in that it doesn't even try to provide a way to solve the issue. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)