# cp fails to copy with errors "cp: error reading 'file': Input/output error" and "cp: failed to extend 'file': Input/output error

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, dmesg, cp

I'm a user of Oracle Virtualbox on Ubuntu. And I used to copy vdi files as a kind of backup. Previously I did this (copying vdi file and then copying it back) many times without any problem.

But today I experienced this error

```
VirtualBox VMs/win_7$ cp ../../Bkps/win_7.vdi .
cp: error reading ‘../../Bkps/win_7.vdi’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘./win_7.vdi’: Input/output error
```

I googled for this a little but from the advices on similar problems I undersood nothing unfortunately. Could anyone suggest how to solve this, please?

The output from the `dmesg` is, (and I understand nothing from it)

```
[ 2347.982876] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1900406f SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 2347.982887] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 2347.982895] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2347.982908] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:70:d0:da:f4/00:00:2e:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq 4096 in
[ 2347.982908]          res 41/40:08:d0:da:f4/00:00:2e:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 2347.982915] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2347.982919] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2348.395657] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2348.395727] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 2348.395733] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2348.395737] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2348.395741] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2348.395745] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 2348.395752] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 2348.395764]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 2348.395770]         2e f4 da d0 
[ 2348.395772] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2348.395774] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2348.395775] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 2348.395776] Read(10): 28 00 2e f4 da d0 00 00 08 00
[ 2348.395781] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 787798736
[ 2348.395792] ecryptfs_decrypt_page: Error attempting to read lower page; rc = [-5]
[ 2348.395795] ata1: EH complete
[ 2348.395797] ecryptfs_readpage: Error decrypting page; rc = [-5]
[ 2351.264987] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x7f80400 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 2351.264998] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 2351.265005] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2351.265019] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:50:d0:da:f4/00:00:2e:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq 4096 in
[ 2351.265019]          res 41/40:08:d0:da:f4/00:00:2e:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 2351.265025] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2351.265029] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2351.403371] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2351.403425] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 2351.403426] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2351.403428] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2351.403429] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2351.403430] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 2351.403433] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 2351.403434]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 2351.403439]         2e f4 da d0 
[ 2351.403442] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2351.403444] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2351.403445] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 2351.403446] Read(10): 28 00 2e f4 da d0 00 00 08 00
[ 2351.403451] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 787798736
[ 2351.403463] ecryptfs_decrypt_page: Error attempting to read lower page; rc = [-5]
[ 2351.403466] ecryptfs_readpage: Error decrypting page; rc = [-5]
[ 2351.403470] ata1: EH complete
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe the disk the vdi file is on if full? Try `df -h`

Comment: Oh, wait - are you doing all this inside virtualbox, or outside?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I do this outside, on my host system. The partition, where the copy is stored and where I try to make a copy has 280GB available, so it is more than enough, as I said I did this operation already many times. I suppose that this can be an error of the HDD

Comment: What is the filesystem on that partition of /dev/sda? (`mount | grep /dev/sda`)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel the output is `/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw)`

Comment: Oh..., so it's ext4, good; And it's your home partition, not so good :)

Comment: Do you still see errors in `dmesg`? You could run a `less +F /var/log/syslog` in a terminal. Theoretically, you could move your users home directory to a different harddisk, so you can unmount `/home', but that sounds a little fragile...

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I see errors in syslog file but they are related to some network problems, may be because I constantly use rdp-client, they look like `Aug 11 17:13:05 dk-l kernel: [18669.464676] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f8:1a:67:7b:1f:ac:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2`

Comment: That's ok - so the disk seems to be alive for now ;)

Comment: I edited the answer a little regarding what to do next: boot a live CD... ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to interpret these errors from syslog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9606/how-to-interpret-these-errors-from-syslog)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is not a "disk" inside a virtualbox, but the real physical disk where the vm images are stored on, that looks pretty bad.

There were read errors, on /dev/sda.
There is an **automatic** handling by marking a disk block as **bad block** forever, and use a different one instead.
For this to work, the harddisk needs to read the data **one single more time**, maybe trying a couple of hundred reads.
But the disk **gave up** on this:

**"Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed"**

There are really bad errors on the disk - it's just not yet clear whether they are in one location only, or spread, and whether they increase with time.

The harddisk may fail very soon,
like **"just now"**.
Or next week, or not at all.

If it does ok on a `e2fsck` test, you cann still not use it for anything important.

As soon as `e2fsck` confirms there are medium errors, best is to just replace it.

Otherwise, make **backups** as soon as possible,
boot a live CD or so (or find a way to unmount/**not mount `/home`**),
and check for bad blocks, like by

`sudo e2fsck -c -v /dev/sdXN`

Take into account that on a larger **mechanical** hard disk, checking for bad blocks may take **lots of time**, between hours and maybe a day or two. That is in part because the program needs to check each disk block separately, and take care of problems separately too. But also, if the disk is giving errors when reading, there are **lots of retries** on multiple levels before `e2fsck` even knows there is a problem. For each disk block.

It may be the right thing to just run `e2fsck` in auto-repair mode and leave the computer alone for a while:

`sudo e2fsck -p -c -v /dev/sdXN`

See [ubuntuforums: Random freeze and "Unrecovered read error" in /var/log/messages](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1720375) for details.

Comment: I did not understand what did you mean with "the real physical disk". This is not a real disk, this is a file which is Virtualbox virtual drive

Comment: Ok, some questions to confirm, I may be wrong: The file `win_7.vdi` is a vm image, right? And it is outside any vms, right? I mean the file `win_7.vdi` is on a real disk - right? The `dmesg` output is from outside the vm, right? In this case, the errors in the `dmesg` log are on a real harddisk /dev/sda.

Comment: yes, "right" to all your questions

Comment: Good - but bad for the disk... can you just replace it? It may fail very soon, like "just now". Or next week, or not at all. If it does ok on a `e2fsck` test, you cann still not use it for anything important.

Comment: And, by the way, is your /home encrypted?

Comment: yes, it is encrypted

Comment: thank you, I decided to replace the hard drive with an SSD soon

Answer (score 11):

For me, I got this error when trying to copy disk images that totaled something like 128GB. `cp` was trying to load the whole thing in memory in order to rewrite it back out and that obviously won't work, so it has to be done in chunks.  The best way I've found to chunk the file is to force it through ssh.

```
scp user@localhost:/path/to/source /path/to/dest
```

You have to use `user@localhost`; omitting it will revert to `cp`-like behavior.

Comment: This is actually a pretty nifty trick. I have a disk that's on the way out and I was getting Input/Output errors while trying to copy data off of it. `scp` saved the day.

Comment: This is wonderful. Never would've come up with it on my own, but it worked on the first try for a 480 GB disk image I was having trouble with.

Comment: I had to enable "Remote Login" under the "Sharing" Settings, first. After that, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The sectors of your hard disk got corrupted.
DRDY ERR - Device Ready Check Error.
UNC - Uncorrectable.

Due to various reasons such as abrupt shut down during extensive write,
High temperature, Read write operations carried out and the quality of hard disk plays a major role in this case.

Once a sector got corrupted and if the kernel tries to access those sectors then you will get this error.

You can use seatools, to recover from this error temporarily.
But will not be to fix this issue forever, It may occur again some times later.

If you are lucky, then it will not reoccur for several days.

Better backup the data to a new hard disk and replace the hard disk.